# Data Annotations will not be working for Textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I created an c# application with mvc4 in that I use one `TextArea` for getting user input which must within the range of 15-100
I use data annotations for that But it will not working.Please anyone help me to solve this problem

Here is my code

```
@Html.TextArea(model => model.Edit)
```

And this is my `DataAnnotations`

```
[MinLength(15,ErrorMessage="Reason can't be less than 15 characters")]
[MaxLength(100,ErrorMessage="Reason can't be more than 100 characters")]
[Display(Name = "Edit" )]
public string Edit{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: The Validation is checking

Comment: Have you added `jquery-validate.js`?

Comment: Yes I added that script file

Comment: Can you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.It will accept all the input data (with any length) it will not validate the input data

Comment: Show the actual html that is being generated by the `TextAreaFor()` method (I assume `@Html.TextArea(model => model.Edit)` is a typo since that would not even compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use this

```
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Must be between {2} and {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 15)]
```

Also, `[Required]` is must